# Saving an array of Entities in another entity with Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have a `Task` entity that should contain an array of `User` entities in a `@OneToMany` relationship.

But I can't figure out a way to store said array without having a link table, since a User may be referenced in multiple `Task`s.

The relationship should look like such, in `TaskEntity`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private Set<UserEntity> users = new HashSet<>(0);
```

What would be the proper way of doing it? How can a single row save an array of entities?

Answer (score 0):

So a User can have many Tasks and each Task can have many Users.

Sounds like a classic fan-trap, you will need a link table and to use `@ManyToMany`.

However the Data-Structure should be modeled before looking into data access implementation.

What you have described is a Many to Many relationship, and your database structure should reflect that, before you think about how you can retrieve the data with Hibernate.

Comment: No, a Task can be managed by an array of Users, and a User can be manager of different Tasks at the same time.

Comment: "said array without having a link table " can you give example how it should looks like in your point of view?

Comment: @Chris Can you show how you would model the data in a Relational Data Base? Then we can look at how to implement hibernate.

Comment: How may I show you that efficiently? I'm on a PostgreSQL database

Comment: @Chris you could post your create scripts.

Comment: I believe Hibernate generates my tables automatically on server launch

Comment: It is possible to configure that, although I am not a fan of that approach. Have you done an ER diagram of hours you wish to store your data?

Comment: Forgive me as I am new to database handling, so the best approaches are not obvious to me. I believe we wish to keep the auto-generation for now as long as we are not in prod.  How may I generate an ER diagram? Is there a go-to tool? Can pgadmin III do such a thing?

Comment: The most important thing with data bases is data integrity. Draw your ER diagram however you wish, I mostly use a white board or a note pad. However  there are lots of tools available to help you draw one on screen. When data modeling this should be step 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid join table (but it is not advised to do so, see below) for unidirectional one-to-many relationship. It would require foreign key to be on the target side of relationship(many side of relationship). You would need to specify a @JoinColumn annotation to point to the foreign key column.

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="TASK_ID")
private Set<UserEntity> users = new HashSet<>(0);
```

It is not advisable, because of the following :
1) Performance : if both UserEntity state and Task states are changed, upon writing to UserEntity the FK to Task is not known, because UserEntity does not have reference to it. So in this case UserEntity might be written twice, once for UserEntity changes and once for Task changes.
2) Mapping : if  UserEntity is assigned to a different task, and there is no reference back to Task from UserEntity, there will be no changes in context.

So it is advisable to go for Join Table in your case.

Comment: Look comment below, chris said that user should be allowed to manage more than one task.

Comment: In this case it is obvious that ManyToMany cardinality with Join Table is required.